# Is requesting downvotes for my own post against the rules?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I would like to see if it's allowed to have people downvote my own post for arbitrary reasons. Is this allowed?

Will I get banned for requesting downvotes on my own posts??

Comment: Asking people to vote *in either direction* is not allowed. It will be edited out of your questions (like any other meta content) and comments will be deleted. At some point, if you persist, you may well get [a day in the penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), as for any other discouraged behaviour.

Comment: Voting rules exist to prevent targeted mass voting by one user to one user. Users' intentions for voting down posts cannot be retrieved anyway. Nobody wins anything from doing this. You (and for answers the downvoter) will lose some reputation. It will probably be edited out as noise/comment will be deleted. If you do this multiple times and somebody notices, moderators might warn you not to post this type of stuff.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, then I should just follow the rules.

Comment: What are these “arbitrary reasons”?

Comment: Considering you were a bit frustrated about a *single* downvote last time you posted a question, you'll have to excuse me but I do not believe you're asking this (rather vague) question in good faith.

Comment: @Marshmallow Yes, not good faith. That's not me. exhale.

Answer (score 13):

Requesting votes (up or down) on any post is not in the spirit of their purpose. Users should vote based on the content of the post alone. And they should not use a user profile to find posts to vote on. Targeting users is by all means a serious offense and those repeatedly involved with it will face consequences.

Votes don't need to be requested. The quality of a post will invite users to use their votes which is much more healthy way to make sure good content can float to the top. Artificially, by social pressure or other means, attracting voters and have them cast votes is hurting the community and the overall trust visitors will have in the content they find on the site.

Comment: While requesting votes is *generally* Not Cricket, you state it "is against the rules". Where?  Neither [the help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), nor the [*Code of Conduct*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) seem to say anything about this (unless the request for votes are done in a harassing or demeaning way).

Comment: @AwesomePoodles that is true. Reworded a bit. No [organized mob voting](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-no-up-down-vote-requests) is a rule in SOCVR.

Comment: Yes, and it should be a rule in general, especially against the "Meta Effect".